# SQL query: multiplication from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say there are 2 tables in a SQL Server database:

`table1`, where prices of products are stored when the prices changes:

```
|Date      |Product|Price|
--------------------------
|2014-01-01|     A |   2$|
|2015-01-01|     A |   3$|
```

`table2`, where quantities of sold products are stored by date:

```
|Date       | Product | Quantities|
-----------------------------------
|2014-01-01 |     A   |    200    |
|2014-06-01 |     A   |    300    |
|2015-02-01 |     A   |    100    |
```

My question: how to calculate sales (Price x Quantities) by date for product by writing a SQL query:

```
|Date       | Product | Sales   |
---------------------------------
|2014-01-01 | A       |     400 |
|2014-06-01 | A       |     600 |
|2015-02-01 | A       |     300 |
```

Comment: What have you tried, exactly? This is not exactly difficult, and involves one of the most fundamental operators in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to pick up the most recent price on or before the sale.  When designing such data structures, it is usually better to have an effective and end date on each record, rather than just the effective date.  Alas, that is not what you have.

You can get the price using a correlated subquery or `apply`.  Here is an example using your column and table names (and assuming that `price` is really stored as a number not a string):

```
select t2.*, (t2.quantity * p.price) as sales
from table2 t2 outer apply
     (select top 1 t1.price
      from table1 t1
      where t1.product = t2.product and t1.date <= t2.date
      order by t1.date desc
     ) p
```

Comment: should be `t2.quantity * p.price` instead of `t2.quantity * t1.price`

Comment: also you should use `order by t1.Date desc` in subselect because subselect will return random price otherwise!

Comment: Gordon, could tell in more details what kind of structure should be used in this case? What are the benefits to have a column "End date" (how it would make easier to query data)?

Comment: This solution also works. Tested. What does (mean) <outer apply> here?

Comment: `outer apply` is an operator in SQL Server.  You can read about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
select [date], product, price*quantities 
from 
(
    select 
    t2.*, t1.price ,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t2.[date], t2.product order by t1.[date] desc) as num
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on  t1.[date] <= t2.[date]
) T
where T.num = 1
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your query. Unfortunately it returns the latest price for all dates.

Comment: Actually it works!. I just changed  "<=" to ">=" and hallelujah:). Could you tell more about query. I do not understand what is does, eg. partition, row number () and etc.

Comment: @deadcode, row_number() is one of ranking functions in sql-server. `partition by t2.[date], t2.product` divide result set into groups of product, sold on certain date; after that `row_number()` set order position of each row in each group according to sorting (`order by t1.[date] desc`). then, applying filter `where T.num = 1` i take the latest price in for everyproduct sold on every date.  see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx